# R: action on many data.frames - how can I speed up my code?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I would like to optimize my code because it takes too long using loops. I prepared a scheme of my problem below.

I want to compare values in the 2nd and 3rd column of two data frames.
As a result I want to get a table after comparing those two data frames that satisfy the requirement:

If values in 2nd column in the first data frame (df) >= values in 2nd column in second data frame (df2) AND values in 3rd column in df <= values in 3r column in df2

so my requirement:

> if(df[i,2] >= df2[j,2] && df[i,3] <= df2[j,3])

My code below works well and does what I want but I think it is not efficient. Does anyone know a function that I can use to improve (speed up) my code?

```
#data frames
L1 = c(65, 61, 70, 65)
L2 = c(150, 135, 210, 140)
Name= c("A","A","A","A")
df = data.frame(Name, L1, L2)

L12 = c(70, 63, 52, 65)
L22 = c(132, 135, 145, 150)
Name2 = c("B","B","B","B")
df2 = data.frame(Name2, L12, L22)

temp <- df[FALSE,]
temp1 <- df2[FALSE,]

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
l = 1
  for (j in 1:nrow(df2)){
    if(df[i,2] >= df2[j,2] && df[i,3] <= df2[j,3]){
     temp[l,] <-df[i,]
     temp1[l,] <-df2[j,]
     l = l + 1
    }
   }
 summ <- cbind(temp, temp1)
  if(i==1){
  sum1 <- summ
  }
  else(sum1 <- rbind(sum1,summ))
temp <- temp[FALSE,]
temp1 <- temp1[FALSE,]
}
```

Additionally, I have to compare lots of data frames each by each. I think the easiest way is to read all my data frames as list and use some function - maybe from apply family? I tried to do it but I am failing. I will be grateful for any tips :)

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do, but why are you using loops? Why can't you just compare the data sets as a whole using just `df[,2] >= df2[,2] & df[,3] <= df2[,3]`?

Comment: because my original data have a different number of rows

Comment: Then what is this code even doing? You're comparing each row in `df` to every row in `df2`? Or are you hoping to only compare the first `i` rows in `df2`?

Comment: I want to compare each row of df with each of df2. As a result I want to get table with all rows (rows from both: df and df2) that satisfy requirement (above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge both data frames first and do the operation afterwards:

```
df.df2 <- merge(df, df2)
df.df2 <- df.df2[with(df.df2, L1 >= L12 & L2 <= L22), ]
df.df2

   Name L1  L2 Name2 L12 L22
10    A 61 135     B  52 145
12    A 65 140     B  52 145
13    A 65 150     B  65 150
16    A 65 140     B  65 150
```

EDIT: Probably this would work in your case, since it doesn't need the creation of a large merged data frame, insted it works bit by bit. The process itself might take longer than the original solution, though.

```
df.df2 <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df.df2.i <- merge(df[i, ], df2)
  df.df2.i <- df.df2.i[with(df.df2.i, L1 >= L12 & L2 <= L22), ]
  df.df2 <- rbind(df.df2, df.df2.i)
}
```

Or using `lapply`

```
df.df2 <- lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) {
  df.df2.i <- merge(df[i, ], df2)
  df.df2.i <- df.df2.i[with(df.df2.i, L1 >= L12 & L2 <= L22), ]
})
df.df2 <- do.call(rbind, df.df2)
```

Comment: I'm afraid my data is too large to use the merge function.  my computer is lagging .. or I am doing something wrong

Comment: What are the sizes of your `df` and `df2`? It is true that the merge will create a large sized data frame

Answer (score 2):

Like others, I'm not completely sure I understand what you want. I think this is what you are after?

```
   lapply(1:nrow(df),function(X) 
                     df[X,1]>=df2[,2]&&df[X,1]<df2[,3]
          )
```

And this returns a list for each row in df, the number of instances your logical test is true

```
 lapply(1:nrow(df),function(X) 
                         sum(df[X,1]>=df2[,2]&&df[X,1]<df2[,3])
              )
```

Additionally, your code contains some basic inefficient statements (e.g. growing data) - that can be detrimental to speed when working with big data. Yet, sometimes we grow data on purpose (unknown size of final product), so you may have done this on purpose.

Anyway, here is a short published [beginners guide on efficient R](http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1004140) code which you can read (focussed on biology - but suitable for all fields).

Hope this helps!

Note: Just saw zyurnaidi's edits. This code is very similar and will be just as efficient as the above if df2 is small - otherwise the repeated merger could slow things down considerably.

Comment: Marco Visser, zyurnaidi - thanks a lot for your answers, tips and comments!! Your ideas were very helpful to me!
I also realized that processing of certain type of data (in my case df ~100 000 rows, df2 ~1500) just takes time so I'm more patient now :)
And thanks for the link to the publication – it's very useful!